# C# Checking for and removing non-ASCII characters from string date field

Tags: c#, date, contains, non-ascii-characters

I am copy/pasting data from Excel to a grid. I am trying to check for any non-ASCII characters and trying to replace them with `string.Empty`.

However, there are date fields too, which could be empty, have non-ASCII character(s) or have date in string format. For each of these that is a date in correct string format then I want to convert it to `DateTime`. Otherwise I want to pass `string.Empty`.

I came across cases where just `"\r"` or `"5/7/2019\r"` is passed and I need help with those.

```
var dtStop = string.Empty;
string StopDate = string.Empty;

if (x.StopDate == null)
    {
        dtStop = string.Empty;
    }
//the line below is not detecting if x.StopDate is just "\r" or if it is "6/7/2018\r"
else if (x.StopDate.Contains("[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]"))
    {

        StopDate = Regex.Replace(x.StopDate ?? string.Empty, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty).Trim();
        if (StopDate != "")
        {
        dtStop = Convert.ToDateTime(StopDate).ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
else
    {
       dtStop = Convert.ToDateTime(x.StopDate).ToShortDateString();
    }
StopDate = dtStop;
```

Comment: As far as I see "\r" is ASCII value. If this is helpful - this regex catches only ASCII values: [^\x00-\x7F]+.

Comment: @AndreySidorenko, In my case string.contains is not detecting it

Comment: this seems to work            else if (x.StopDate.Contains("[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]") || x.StopDate.Contains("\r") || x.StopDate.Contains("\n") || x.StopDate.Contains("\r\n")) although \u000A is linefeed and \u000D is carriage return

Comment: This one works for me - Regex.Replace("5/7/2019\r", "[^ -~]", "")